# Resistance between any two point with unknown current direction

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

A resistor-network which can be expressed as a weighted, undirected graph (like the following figures).

The Y-Δ transform shows: the effective resistance between any two points could be written as a function of all resistance in the network:

$$R_{ij}=F\left({ R_{1}, R_{2}, R_{3}, ... }\right)$$

Thus, for a network with finite resistors, is there a general method to get such a function, without using the transforms?

---

THE following is NOT a question, NOT anything HOMEWORK-LIKE, it's an example for showing what is a "weighted undirected graph".

---

Such as some resistance network like following, the weighted edges are the resistance. Is it possible to write down the resistance between "one node" and "the other node" as a expression of edge weights like $$R_{one node - the other node}=F{(e_{AF},e_{AF},e_{AB},e_{AH},e_{BH},.....)}$$

[image]
[image]

The google shows many methods, but the current direction for every resistance is necessary.

If anyone has a method do not need the current direction? That's nice if you can share a simple example (or a link), thank you.

---

-

-

Here is a method I saw, but it requires all resistors have the same resistance.

where $L_{ii}=$ edges connected to the node $v_{i}$

and $L_{ij} = -1$ if $v_{i}$ connected with $v_{j}$, else $L_{ij}=0$

[image]

### How about when the resistance is not $R$ but unknown values: $e_{1}=R_{1}, e_{2}=R_{2}, e_{3}=R_{3}$ and $e_{4}=R_{4}$

Comment: Resistances don't have a "direction". The resistance of the network will be the same for any potential difference applied between A and F. (And if you reverse the voltage, the currents will all reverse). So, if you can solve a circuit with voltages and currents, you can solve this one. Also, there are transformations such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-Δ_transform) which may help. *Please note* that actually solving this circuit for you would be off-topic for this site, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidance.

Comment: The current does have a direction. It's better to do not focus on "A" or "F" as I'm asking a general question: effective resistance between ANY two points of any resistance network which can be expressed as a weighted, undirected graph.

Comment: @LonelyProf Yep, the current has a direction. but I'm asking a general question: effective resistance between ANY two points of ANY resistance network which can be expressed as a weighted, undirected graph (for example, I put two pictures). The transformations such as you mentioned shows: the effective resistance could be written as a function of each resistance in the network. Thus, Physically, I believe there should be a more general method to calculate this effective resistance. I'm looking for such a method (with examples) If anyone knows this method is observed.

Comment: That's fine. Are you aware of [Thevenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thévenin's_theorem) which provides such an approach as an alternative to [Kirchoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).

Comment: Solving these R problems gives will give n linear equations for n current paths and a computer can be used to solve the linear matrix.  A 5 resistor network can have 5 equations for example.  An algebraic solution to  a matrix is possible but it gets very large very quickly with increasing n.  I would think a clever computer program could likely generate the  n linear equations given any system but then you would need to use the matrix equations which are available for a 2x2 or 3x3 but get huge thereafter.

Comment: @PhysicsDave  Is a linear matrix can be given only when all resistors have the same resistance? I saw a website say that for arbitrary resistance, the size of the matrix depends on the resistance of each resistor.

Comment: The matrix size only depends upon the number of current paths in the circuit, the resistor values can be any size. You should also look at how matrices are solved using determinants etc ...